# test if a toast message was shown with Jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, toast

I'm testing my react native application with Jest and I want to test when toast shows a message.

I'm using toast like this in one of my callbacks :

```
if (pinMismatch) {
       Toast.show({
              type: "error",
              text1: "invalid answer",
       });
}
```

And I want to check in my test below that the message is shown :

```
    it('handles unsuccessful registration due to PIN mismatch', async () => {
        const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(
                    <NavigationContainer>
                               <Registration navigation={mockNavigation} />
                    </NavigationContainer>
              );

        fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId('pin'), '123456');
        fireEvent.changeText(getByTestId('confirm-pin'), '654321');
        const registrationButton = getByText("register");
        fireEvent.press(registrationButton);

        await waitFor(() => {
                 // I want to check here that "invalid answer" was shown
        }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getByText` matcher, or the async `findByText` matcher if the toast is shown asynchronously and you need to wait for it to appear.

```js
test('...', async () => {
  //...
  expect(await screen.findByText('invalid answer')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```